# Youtube API, creating a playlist. Returns HttpError 400

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

Hey everyone I'm trying to create a **Python** script that will create a playlist on my youtube channel.

I've already have the OAuth working, and have both of these scopes in here :

```
 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"
```

Here is the build with the OAuth credential in:

```
youtube_service = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
```

This is how I try to call the API:

```
resource={'defaultLanguage': 'EN',
 'description': 'test',
 'title': 'Information Security'}

response = youtube_service.playlists().insert(
        body=resource,
        part='snippet,status',

    ).execute()
```

This then throws the 400 error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet%2Cstatus&alt=json returned "Must specify playlist title.". Details: "[{'message': 'Must specify playlist title.', 'domain': 'youtube.playlist', 'reason': 'playlistTitleRequired'}]">
```

I tryed a few different ways for changing the playlist insert request but I allways get the same error, and I have had no sucess with the google Docs.

Comment: body should be a [playlistresource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists#resource)  thats not the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much knowledge in Python but maybe the info on this link might be helpful (There's a create a playlist part): https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python

Also, try changing your json this way (because the api is telling you that is something wrong with the body request):

```
{
   "defaultLanguage":"EN",
   "description":"test",
   "title":"Information Security"
}
```